# Visual studio c# remote debugging closes windows service

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

Im debugging my windows service occasionally from my computer when in fact the windows service is in a different far server.
Im using the visual studio remote debugger to do so and then attaching my source to the service by connecting to the server via the

> tools -> attach to process -> qualifier = server ip

The issue is that whenever I lose connection with the server due to internet error or etc, the windows server stops and shuts down in my server and I have to start it again.

Perhaps I haven't provided enough information, so please ask for it instead of down vote.

TIA.

Comment: I would suggest putting a `try/catch` in the windows service, and see if it crashes for some reason. If it does, and the connection is the reason, it might give you a bit more to continue with.

Comment: When I've developed services, I usually build them in two forms: one a service and the other a console app, such that they differ only in the "wrapper" code necessary to run them in their respective contexts. I use the console version to develop/debug my code and simply build the service when ready to deploy. I have never needed to attach to/debug a service process.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but its not the issue..
try and catch i think its redundant because i know for sure its the connection error from my local computer and not the server..
regarding the console, i also ran the service locally to track for it, the remote is only for specific circumstances..

Comment: So you can't simulate what happens when the code is ran in a service instead in a console App?
As my advice will also be to just create a console app and debug that instead of the service process itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check Event Viewer on the remote server.  There should be an entry in the Application log if the service crashed.  If you need more details, you can have Windows Error Reporter capture a crash dump when the service crashes.  Details are here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

GitHub recommends this as debugging procedure for their Windows client.  You can grab the .reg file from here and tweak it to match your path/executable.  https://help.github.com/articles/getting-a-crash-dump/

Then you can bring the .dmp file to your machine and inspect it in Visual Studio / Windbg/SOS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540665(v=vs.85).aspx